Rebuild the hierarchy from a one column dataframe
I have the following dataframe:
   Name       Qty

0  Fruits

1  Apple      100

2  Mango      200

3  Vegetables 

4  spinach     2

I want to rebuild the hierarchy of the dataset by using the category 'Fruits' and 'Vegetables', whose values in the column 'Qty' are empty strings. The output needed is:
   Category     Constituents    Qty

0  Fruit        Apple           100

1  Fruit        Mango           200

2  Vegetables   Spinach          2


What is the most efficient way to perform this dataframe transformation to rebuild the hierarchy of my dataset considering that my initial dataframe actually is a very big one with thousands of rows ( here I just gave a short example to dhow what I want to achieve)
Thanks in advance
That is

One approach to doing this is to forward Fill the categories ('Fruits', 'Vegetables', etc.) to create a new 'Category' column, filter uot the original category rows and finally rename and reorganize what is needed.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'Name': ['Fruits', 'Apple', 'Mango', 'Vegetables', 'Spinach'],
    'Qty': [np.nan, 100, 200, np.nan, 2]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Category'] = df['Name'].where(df['Qty'].isna()).ffill()

filtered_df = df.dropna(subset=['Qty'])

final_df = filtered_df[['Category', 'Name', 'Qty']].copy()
final_df.columns = ['Category', 'Constituents', 'Qty']

final_df


which return
     Category Constituents    Qty
1      Fruits        Apple  100.0
2      Fruits        Mango  200.0
4  Vegetables      Spinach    2.0


Thanks for the answer. But considering that the initial dataframe will have thousands of rows, is this method efficient and quick, considering all the instructions used?
